# Translate inside a computed with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to translate the status in this code:

```
computed: {

    variant() {
      if (status === this.$t("vue.pending") || this.$t("vue.not_contract")) {
        return "warning";
      } else if (status === this.$t("vue.confirmed")) {
        return "success";
      } else if (status === this.$t("vue.expired") || this.$t("vue.declined")) {
        return "error";
      } else {
        return "dark";
      }
    },
  },
```

i tried put this.$t but it doesn't works.

the template is :

```
    <div class="mt-2">
 <b-badge :variant="variant">
  {{ contract.status }}</b-badge>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

Console return this error:
[vue-i18n] Value of key 'vue.not_contract' is not a string or function !
[vue-i18n] Cannot translate the value of keypath ‘vue.not_contract’. Use the value of keypath as default.

I arranged like this:
template:

```
<div class="mt-2">
   <b-badge :variant="variant">
     {{ $t(contract.status) }}</b-badge>
  </div>
```

Script:

```
computed:{
variant() {
      if (status === "pending" || "not_contract") {
        return "warning";
      } else if (status === "confirmed") {
        return "success";
      } else if (status === "expired" || "declined"){
        return "error";
      } else {
        return "dark";
      }
    },
}
```

Comment: Nothing was improved since the previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70394734/translate-inside-if-condition-with-vuejs# . You still need to provide a way to reproduce the problem if you're interested in solving your problem. It's unknown what doesn't work means in your case. If there are errors, they need to be listed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You cannot access `this` within computed properties, so therefore (afaik) it's not possible to use vue-18n here. Instead, you'll need to handle this login in the `methods` section.

Comment: Errror : [vue-i18n] Value of key 'vue.not_contract' is not a string or function !

Comment: @Alicia and in my template how can i call this methods?

Comment: So using methods would be pretty much exactly the same as computed values, except they go under the `methods` section, the method will need to return a value, and when you call it, you'll need to include the parenthesis `()` (unlike with computed). For syntax, see the methods section [of this page in the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers)

Comment: @Alicia `You cannot access this within computed properties` ....this is not true

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declare `status` in your data section, even if its value is `undefined`, or it will not be reactive.

```
data(){
 return {
  status: undefined
  // or status: 'pending', etc
 }
}
```